# What is the attribute to stop windows form designer from setting a property

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I have been using [System.ComponentModel.ReadOnly] on user controls to prevent the designer from setting properties but I have read some things which indicate 
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)] should be used for this purpose. Which is correct? If its not [System.ComponentModel.ReadOnly], when should this attribute be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it does that, but not its intention.  [ReadOnly(true)] prevents the user from modifying the property in the Properties window.  It still shows up, but is grayed-out.  The odds that this is actually useful are rather small, I can't think of a good example.  A possible corner-case is a custom TypeDescriptor that dynamically changes the read-only state, depending on other property values.  But that is rocket science.

You normally use [Browsable(false)] to prevent the property from showing up.  And DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden to stop the code serializer from preserving a value in the InitializeComponent() method, one that is unlikely to be useful if the user can't modify it. Albeit that the [DefaultValue] would typically already ensure that.  YMMV.

Comment: Thanks I want to be able set the properties I marking in the constructor of control / forms that host the controls whose properties I am marking. When I used ReadOnly it seemed to cause MethodNotFound exceptions in the designers - is that to be expected?

Comment: Hmm, no.  It is an easy exception to generate, just modifying the control without also removing it from the form first can do it.  I should not require me to guess at this with so little info to work from, click the Ask Question button.